# "Indentation Error: unexpected indent" in python

Tags: python, django

So I am learning from Django Tutorials, and at the middle part of the [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/), I have to make some changes in **mysite\polls\views.py**

This is how I have made the changes in `class IndexView` and `class DetailView` as asked:

**mysite\polls\views.py:**

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self): #The Error Points Here
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

**mysite\polls\urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    ]
```

AND, This is the error I get: **(Note that that my indentation is proper as expected)**

ALSO, the below Traceback is of just 1 test error, there are 6 **SIMILAR TEST ERRORS WITH EXACT TRACEBACK**

```
PS E:\ict\python\mysite> python manage.py test polls
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
EE.EEEEE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_detail_view_with_a_future_question  (polls.tests.QuestionIndexDetailTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\ict\python\mysite\polls\tests.py", line 113, in test_detail_view_with_a_future_question
args=(future_question.id,)))
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 568, in reverse
app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 360, in app_dict
self._populate()
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 293, in _populate
for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "E:\ict\python\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 52, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "E:\ict\python\mysite\polls\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import views
File "E:\ict\python\mysite\polls\views.py", line 23
def get_queryset(self): #From The DetailView Class
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I tried searching about this error, but all it asks is to properly indent the code, which it already is.

Comment: could you name your functions get_queryset in two different manners, so the stacktrace is a bit clearer? line 23 isn't saying much if we only see part of the code

Comment: @iScrE4m The get_queryset error points from the DetailView Class. I have edited the question to clear out the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you mixed tabs with spaces.

Comment: Oh my God. It Worked! The unusual appearance of a scope in NotePad++ disappeared as well!

Answer (score 2):

This happens all the time for me, especially if you do any cutting and pasting code.   Sometimes you'll end up with a space in the tab, but it still "looks" like it's all the same.   I would suggest setting your editor up to use spaces for tabs (I use four spaces for a tab), then go back in and delete all the indents, then add them back and you'll have a consistent 4 space/tab indents and that should fix your issue.

Comment: I didn't knew I could set spaces for a tab in my editor. I'll do that first thing! Thank you. :)

Comment: @Mr.Robot If you are on windows I suggest using sublime2 as an editor

Comment: Yes... sublime2 is fantastic.  Atom.io is very similar as well.   Both are cross platform and are fantastic.  If you use git, you can also integrate git into the both of the editors via plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Often word processors replace tabs with spaces, however this is not the case. Occasionally if you use tabs with spaces on the same document, the interpreter doesn't like it.

Often if this error happens, it is just as likely to be within the spacing of the last like above, as well as the line flagged. I suggest deleting all the whitespace and redoing those to lines.

If the same error appears further up, it is a tab/space issue, so just keep redoing the whitespace until it stops.

Alternatively vim can do indentation using <<  and >> in normal mode.